# mariadb, 0% innodb read buffer efficiency

Tags: mariadb

I have a dedicated server running Mariadb 11.1.3. I am trying to tune the database using mysqltuner.pl.
In the results I got this results on the Innodb:

```
-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB Buffer Pool size ( 1.0G ) under limit for 64 bits architecture: (17179869184.0G )
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 1.0G / 493.0M
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 256.0M * 1/1.0G should be equal to 25%
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk: 64 for 1 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
 [!!] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 0% (-19040 hits / 0 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 88.69% (239467 hits / 270003 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 30536 writes)
```

I searched the internet for the reason why the read buffer efficiency is 0% but I can't find anything about it.

My my.cnf:

```
    [client-server]
    socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

    [mysqld]
    skip_name_resolve = ON
    join_buffer_size = 1M
    tmp_table_size = 64M
    max_heap_table_size = 64M
    table_definition_cache = 4096
    performance_schema = ON
    innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1024M
    query_cache_limit=8M
    query_cache_size=256M
    query_cache_type=1
    innodb_log_file_size = 256M
    slow_query_log = 1
    slow-query_log_file = /var/log/mysql-slow.log
    long_query_time = 1

    !includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
    !includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
```

Any ideas where to look for this problem?

I allready tried several settings and compared with a existing system.

Thanks,
Roger

Comment: Do you care? (If yes, why?) The buffer efficiency indicator is probably bogus anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72029059/innodb-write-log-efficiency-is-too-high-more-than-100-1953-15

Comment: Well, I am trying to find the reason behind a slow TTFB and 0% seems to indicate that something is not working. I don't really care if it was 60% or 120%, but 0% seems not good to me.

Comment: So that's probably the more interesting question. The indicator is clearly broken and likely has nothing to do with your problem. Can you expand on the real problem that you are solving?

Comment: Please post the complete report from MySQLTuner.pl so we have a few more important details, such as Total Ram available.  Welcome to SO.

Comment: The server has 8Gb of ram, but the problem on the slow TTFB is very complicated. I brought the WP site back to WP, Woocommerce, Elementor and the theme, but was still to slow. But I'll ask that in a seperate question later ;-).

Comment: This plugin improves performance for many WP queries:  [_WP Index Improvements_](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)  Meanwhile, what are the 'worst' queries as discovered by the  [_SlowLog_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was [a bug](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-32920) in the 11.1.3 release, `Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests` wasn't being incremented hence negative hits. It will be fixed in the next release 11.1.4.