Innodb - Can you safely ignore the warning "Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size"
We get this warning in our online shop

report.WARNING: Memory size allocated for the temporary table is more
than 20% of innodb_buffer_pool_size. Please update
innodb_buffer_pool_size or decrease batch size value (which decreases
memory usages for the temporary table). Current batch size: 589;
Allocated memory size: 1742262000 bytes; InnoDB buffer pool size:
8589934592 bytes.

So I ran mysqltuner to analyse the database settings and it recommends to set the innodb_buffer_pool_size to >13.7GB. It is set to 8GB currently.
We expect very high customer traffic on january, so I asked my supervisor if I am allowed to increase the value to about 14 GB (we have 12 GB free RAM), but according to him it is just a warning and we should ignore it until we switch to another hoster in march.
According to my research, this misconfiguration can lead to performance loss and even cause transactions to fail and ulitimately cause bugs. Is this really just a warning that one can ignore?
What is the worst case that can happen when ignored?

mysqltuner is useless, better delete/remove it. See Configuring InnoDB Buffer Pool Size how to properly set innodb_buffer_pool_size

Ok, thank you. My supervisor recommended it. Why do you think that it is useless?

In my opinion and experience it often gives generic recommendation and it does not understand your workload

I also recommending binning mysqltuner. I've seen cases where it confidently makes recommendations that are based on incorrect knowledge of how MySQL works. See for example my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72032405/20860
